# passing two identical parametrs to access database

Tags: c#

From the C# code, I am trying to execute a query and pass two parmeters to Access database. Unforunately the parameter name is same beacuse I am passing  date parameter. It seems when i exceute the code the first parametr is replaced by the second parameter so for e.g I am passing

Startdate as 1/1/2017 and end date as 1/31/2017

I am still getting the 2016 values.

Below is my code

```
string ConnString = getConnstring();
        string DirectoryPath = getDirectortyPath(year, quater);
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(DirectoryPath);
        string StartDate = calculateStartDate(year, quater);
        string EndDate = CalculateEndDate(year, quater);
        string SqlString = "Select * from TestTable where compl_date >= ? and compl_date <= ?";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))

        {

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))

            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compl_date", StartDate); // startDate can be 1/1/2017
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compl_date", EndDate);  // end date could be 1/31/2017
                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

                {

                    while (reader.Read())

                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string FullLine = "";
```

How can I get the values that are within the above date range.

Comment: You're using the same parameter name for both start and end dates. So when you call cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compl_date", EndDate);  it puts the end date in both places. You need different parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this;

```
string ConnString = getConnstring();
            string DirectoryPath = getDirectortyPath(year, quater);
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(DirectoryPath);
            string StartDate = calculateStartDate(year, quater);
            string EndDate = CalculateEndDate(year, quater);
            string SqlString = "Select * from TestTable where compl_date >= @StartDate and compl_date <= @EndDate";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))    
            {    
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);  
                    conn.Open();
....
```

Comment: I'd add another using to the stream writer to make sure it gets closed as well.